# Handbrake is slow at converting audio

Tags: mac, conversion, handbrake

My conversion in Handbrake is taking forever (over 24hrs). The video conversion is done in a few minutes, but then I get miles of this over and over again:

> sync: adding 102 ms of silence to audio 32957  start 509936298, next 509927040

I'm converting a DVD (instructional type) to iPod format. Does anyone have a fix? I have tried other formats on this DVD (normal and others) and get the same "audio adding silence" bit, line after line for hours.